# Managing many GB's of data on disk, direct access

Tags: c++, file, binary

I'm trying to find out if I'm willing to go through the trouble of solving a problem that captured my interest. In order to solve the problem, I will need to create a binary file of more than one TB. If I'm very lucky, this can be reduced to around 300GB, which would be the very minimum of memory required to solve my problem. Obviously, the data can't be kept in RAM, so I have to figure out how and when to write to (and read from) disk.

I guess the usual ways of writing to disk are out of the question. An `fstream` will fail miserably when it tries to load the file into memory. Does anyone here know about (preferably portable) techniques that can read and write directly to disk without first caching (parts of) the data? It also occurred to me that I might not even need a filesystem to do this. Can't I just flip bits on the disk directly (without using emacs' `M-x butterfly`)?

Comment: It *appears* from the description that data will have to be written and read using direct access. Therefore, the data structure underlying this data will have to be designed carefully. Packing (or careful arranging) of structure fields, using the smallest possible intN_t, etc.

Comment: @laune I actually plan on manipulating single bits. Every bit in the 300GB corresponds to a certain state, which I need to *check*.

Comment: "Obviously, the data can't be kept in RAM". No? It's not _that_ excessive. Unfortunately Amazon only has 244GB instances, but there are plenty of commercial server designs that happily support 1TB RAM.

Comment: @MSalters Haha okay okay, you're right. But I want to do it right here on my laptop, if at all possible. If not, screw it... after all it's just a toy project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a memory-mapped file (on a 64-bit system) is exactly what you need.

You simply map the whole file into memory and manipulate it just like a normal data structure; the operating system takes care of loading and unloading the data to/from memory.

It's not standard C++, but there is a [Boost implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) that should work on major platforms.

Comment: Just to be clear, the Boost implementation will also work for files that don't fit into the system memory? I just found out that the Virtual address space on a 64-bit system can be 8TB large, so that should work, right?

Comment: @JorenHeit: Yes, as long as you have enough address space left (which you practically always do in 64-bit), the file is "there" in memory. The fact that it's not *actually* loaded in memory is irrelevant to the program; the program can pretend the whole thing is there.

Comment: @JorenHeit Before you shell out the dough, consider the 300GB with one bit per state, and operations for setBit and clearBit. Memory mapping a file means that pages (size depends on the OS, assume 4K) are read and written, so you'll have this for a single bit operation. Of course, pages are held in memory as long as possible, but eventually pages will have to be swapped out. So, the overall behaviour depends on the "locality" of your program, i.e., the non-randomness of its bit accesses. Take care - a test might show whether it'll be feasible in the end.

Comment: @laune Thanks for the tips. I'm already using one bit per state, and I think many of the reads and writes will be close to eachother, but I'm not sure *how* close... We'll see :-)